# Synchronization problem in JAVA multithreading environment together with stream interface

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I am having trouble with a rather complicated multithreading problem:

- I run a service pushing data to an activeMQ message queue, completely independent from the actual appication I am running
- The data pushed to ActiveMQ is being picked up and processed via an Apache Camel Processor where listeners can register to be notified about new processor results.
- The actual application is a listener to the Camel processor. It drives a process via the stream() interface, kicking off new threads at each processing step.

The goal is that the code in the separate thread waits for the result of the ActiveMq-processor. I believe that I have to use some thread locking or latch but I do not have enough experience in JAVA multithreading to make this work.

Code of processing class:

```
public class MyApplication {

    CallingInstanceIF _callingInstance = null;
    ActiveMQConnector _activemqConector = null;
    Data _dataFromApacheCamelProcessor = null;

    public MyApplication(CallingInstanceIF callingInstance) throws Exception {

        _callingInstance = callingInstance;

        // start apache camel route to ActiveMQ server. 
        //This pushes data at arrival to method doOnDataArrival() below
        try {
            _activemqConnector = new ActiveMQConnector(this);
            _activemqConnector.startConnections();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }

    private ResultDataStructure methodExecutedInSeparateThread(inputData) {

            _doSomethingLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            _callingInstance.setCountDownLatch(_doSomethingLatch);
            ResultDataStructure output = new ResultDataStructure();

            try {
               // do something in calling instance. 
               // This is done synchronously in other thread
                resultOfDoSomething = _callingInstance.doSomething(inputData);
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                ...
            }

            // wait for _callingInstance to 
            // finish --> _callingInstance lifts _doSomethingLatch (working code up to here)
            try {
                _doSomethingLatch.await();
            } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                ...
            }

            output.add(resultOfDoSomething);

            // Here is where I have problems: 
            //this method shall for result arriving from method doOnDataArrival() below

            waitForCamelResult();
            output.add(_dataFromApacheCamelProcessor);


        return output

    }

    public void initAlgorithm(final Object scanParameters) throws Exception {

                _scannerEngine = Engine.builder(this::methodExecutedInOtherThread, inputData) //
                        .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()) // Executor kicks off "methodExecutedInSeparateThread()" above
                        .build();

        }
    }

    public void mainProcessingMethod(final BiConsumer<...> callback) throws Exception {

        final Thread processingThread = new Thread(() -> {

            try {
                _scannerEngine.stream() //
                        .limit(... limit criteria) //
                        .forEach(processResult -> {
                            waiting();
                            if (callback != null) {
                                    callback.accept(evolutionResult, best.max());
                                }
                            }
                        });

            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                ...
            }

            _callingInstance.doOnAlgorithmFinished();
        });

        processingThread.start();
        _engineStream = processingThread;
    }    

    public void doOnDataArrival(dataFromApacheCamelProcessor) {

        _dataBuffer = dataFromApacheCamelProcessor;

        shall notify "methodExecutedIn
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot refer to the code above but according from what I understand there are two java constructs that might be able to help you.

[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) ([Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture)) can help you if you need to send of a thread and wait for a single response. Using `supplyAsync` and `get`.

Or if you need to deliver multiple "shots" with one instance you could use  [SynchronousQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) ([Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronous-queue)) (Blocking queue.). Basically calling `put` and `take`.

Comment: Hi Ben, I managed to realize the functionality I need using a static CoundownLatch which is instantiated in the methodExecutedInSeparateThread() and counted down in doOnDataArrival(). This works, maybe it is not very elegant... Played as well around with Futures but this was more difficult to use.